# Finding the normal from one 3d vector/line to any point on another 3d vector/line

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have two 3d vectors, `v1` and `v2` (you can consider them both lines if you like). I'm trying to figure out a normal for `v1` so that it intersects along any point of `v2`.

I keep drawing blanks on this one. It's easy enough to find a vector that points from `v1` to `v2` (just do `v2 - v1`), but that result isn't always perpendicular to `v1`.

How would you go about making that result perpendicular to `v1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scalar projection, i.e. the dot product, to do that.

You want to project v2 onto v1, so normalize v1 to length 1, then take the dot product: `float projection = dot(v2, normalize(v1));`

This tells you how far you have to go in the direction of v1 until you are perpendicular to the end of v2, so `float scalar = projection / length(v1);` tells you where on v1 that point is.

so `scalar * v1` gets you to that point, and `v2 - scalar*v1` would be the perpendicular vector from that point on v1 to v2.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I knew the solution had something to do with that - I was trying the cross product between `v1` and `v2`, and then the cross product again between `v1` and the previous result - still wasn't working how I thought it should. Thank again!